# Polynomial Evaluation

Tags: matlab, matrix, polynomial-math

I read a Matlab tutorial script and I'm not sure how the function `polyvalm` works.

The polynomial is as follow: p(X)=X^3 -2*X -5I (where I is the identity matrix)

polynomial coefficients of `p(X)`is `[1 0 -2 -5]`

`X = [2 4 5; -1 0 3; 7 1 5];
Y = polyvalm(p,X)`

My interpretation is `X.^3 - 2*X -5*eye(3)` but my result is totally different.

Sorry for the ugly typesetting but stack overflow doesn't offer Latex so can't help it

Comment: is your p vector of coefficients : `p = [1 0 -2 -5]` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. Thanks, I will include it in the question for clarity

Comment: I believe the identity matrix is misleading you. polyvalm makes no mention of the polynomial `p` taking on a matrix form, only `X` Can you link the tutorial script you read?

Answer (score 1):

You are using element wise cube (`X.^3`) which is of course different from actually cubing a matrix. So for your `p` the polynomial is actually `X^3 - 2*X - 5*eye(size(X))`:

```
p = [1 0 -2 -5];
X = [2 4 5; -1 0 3; 7 1 5];

% anonymous function to illustrate
f = @(X,p) p(1)*X^3 + p(2)*X^2 + p(3)*X + p(4)*eye(size(X));

y_polyvalm = polyvalm(p,X)
y_fun = f(X,p)
```

This results in

```
y_polyvalm =

   377   179   439
   111    81   136
   490   253   639

y_fun =

   377   179   439
   111    81   136
   490   253   639
```